# Adding column to CSV leaves single quote around first record

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm using a CSV to import into a hash table for another PS script; however, I need to add a column to the CSV with the string `FALSE` populating the column.

```
"Culture\\Cities_ArcGIS"
"Culture\\Counties_ArcGIS"
"Culture\\States_ArcGIS"
```

```
(Import-Csv U:\To_Delete\Layer_search\WB_layers-mod.csv) |
    Select-Object *,@{Expression={'FALSE'}} |
    Export-Csv U:\To_Delete\Layer_search\WB_layers-mod.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This script works well except for one thing: it leaves single quotes around the first string in the added column (`"'FALSE'"`) like this:

```
"Culture Data\\Cities_ArcGIS","'FALSE'"
"Culture Data\\Counties_ArcGIS","FALSE"
"Culture Data\\States_ArcGIS","FALSE"
```

How do I keep the single quotes from surrounding the first string in the new column?

Comment: Your output file isn't a csv, it doesn't use commas to delimit the columns (or have headers)... can you include a sample of the input file? With any identifying data removed for privacy (just `xxxxxx` it out).

Comment: I just structured the output like it looks in Excel for easier reading. It is really a CSV with commas where the spaces would be.

Comment: Excel hides the file structure and formatting, so using raw data is better for us to be able to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't want to do process the data in the file, we can treat the file as plain text and just add the string `,"FALSE"` to the end of each line:

```
(Get-Content U:\To_Delete\Layer_search\WB_layers-mod.csv) | 
    foreach {$_ + ',"FALSE"'} |
    Set-Content U:\To_Delete\Layer_search\WB_layers-mod.csv
```

This will take:

```
"Culture\\Cities_ArcGIS"
"Culture\\Counties_ArcGIS"
"Culture\\States_ArcGIS"
```

And output:

```
"Culture Data\\Cities_ArcGIS","FALSE"
"Culture Data\\Counties_ArcGIS","FALSE"
"Culture Data\\States_ArcGIS","FALSE"
```

Comment: Thank you, James! Your solution actually helped me refine my script and answered some other questions I had. I really appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be that your CSV file doesn't have any headers.

Here's how to read a CSV file with no headers (assuming you know how many columns there are):

```
$csvFile = 'U:\To_Delete\Layer_search\WB_layers-mod.cs'
$headers = 'Column1' #add column headers here as needed; e.g. 'Column1','Column2','etc.'
$data = Import-CSV -Path $csvFile -Header $headers
```

You've now imported your data, keeping the first line, and giving all columns names so they're treated as properties on an array of custom objects.

You already know how to add your new property/column:

```
$data = $data | Select-Object *, @{Name='NewColumn';Expression={$false}}
```

Above I used `$false` instead of `'False'`, but it makes little difference here, both will create the same output in your final CSV.

Finally you need to output your new data to CSV.  To do this you need a way to create a CSV file without headers.  There's no `-NoHeader` option, so the trick here is to switch `Export-Csv` for `ConvertTo-CSV`, which creates an in-memory CSV; then use `Select-Object -Skip 1` to skip the first item in the array (which is the header row), then use `Set-Content` to persist this data to a file:

```
$data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content -Path $csvFile -Force
```

NB: [James's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53671834/361842) is better in terms of simplicity and performance.  This answer's provided to show a more CSV friendly approach; in case you wanted to treat your data more like a real CSV (e.g. use data from existing columns / that sort of thing) rather than just manipulating strings in files.

Answer (score 0):

To fix issue with calculated column just add name to it

```
import-csv test.csv | select  *, @{Name="FALSE"; Expression={"FALSE"}}
```

Although just appending "FALSE" as a string is a better idea.

Comment: Sometimes I get wrapped up in the idea of CSV files in Excel and forget that they are just a text file.